# Close a scanner object while executing .next() method? java

Tags: java, sockets, java.util.scanner

I have a simple question, Im making an online game (getting down the basics before I move to the GUI) and I have some commands, for example if a user inputs 'q' in the console the program will terminate (will quite), but if an error happens somewhere else in the code (i.e. cant find the server) I close all the connects/attempted connections. I also want to close the scanner object but the scanner object is holding on the ".next()" method. I tried calling ".close()" and ".reset()", etc. but nothing will make the scanner object halt. How can I stop the scanner object so I can make a full close of the program?

-Dan

```
public void commands(){
    char[] charArray;
    while(running){
        String input = scanCommands.next();
        if(input.length() > 1){
            command = 'x';
        }else{
            charArray = input.toCharArray();
            command = charArray[0];
        }
        switch(command){
            case 'h':
                System.out.println("Server Commands: ");
                System.out.println("Command:     Function:");
                System.out.println(" q        -   to exit the server.");
                System.out.println("done.");
                break;
            case 'q':
                System.out.println("Quiting...");
                quite();
                System.out.println("done.");
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid server command");
                break;
        }
    }
}

//the quite method is the one that I call and should close everything, including the 
//scanner object.

public void quite(){
    running = false;
    try{
        IS.close();
        OS.close();
        send.close();
        recieve.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        IS = null;
        OS = null;
        send = null;
        recieve = null;
    }
    String[] nullNames = new String[7];
    name.setArray(nullNames);
}
```

UPDATE:
I use to have ".close()" in the quite method but it didnt work. I tried it again and entered debug mode mode and it just holds on ".close()". Once I type in 'q' or anything, the code continues, and the ".close()" is executed. How can I close it without typing anything?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. What are all these streams? What does the peer code look like? And the word you're looking for is 'quit', not 'quite'.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the Scanner object because it is not in the try-block.

```
try{
    IS.close();
    OS.close();
    send.close();
    recieve.close();
}
```

should include

```
scanCommands.close();
```

If this throws an exception, include that with your question.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround you can try to check hasNext before every call of next method.